# Coffeescript printing HTML on page, not rendering it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coffeescript, meteor

So, I'm working on a small Meteor project, and I've written a template helper that looks at a property of the current document (iterating through them to display), and at one point, makes a logic decision based on this property and is supposed to output HTML accordingly.

The logic works fine, but when I use this Coffeescript:

```
Template.formQuestion.helpers

    formArrows: ->

        maxOrder = Questions.findOne({},{sort: {"order", 1}}).order
        questionOrder = Questions.findOne(this._id, {fields: {'order': 1}}).order

        console.log "max order: #{maxOrder}, current order: #{questionOrder}"

        # Check to see what arrows to render
        if questionOrder == 1
            "<i class='fa fa-chevron-circle-down'></i>"
        else if questionOrder < maxOrder
            "<i class='fa fa-chevron-circle-up'></i> | <i class='fa fa-chevron-circle-down'></i>"
        else
            "<i class='fa fa-chevron-circle-up'></i>"
```

I get the following output:

[image: Coffeescript Issue Example]

Why is it that it's printing the HTML on the page instead of rendering it?   Should I be manipulating the DOM using JQuery or something instead?  I'm sort of new to JS, and decided to learn Coffeescript as I went, because I've heard such good things about it.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the issue was due to Handlebars escaping my HTML when it was being output.

I needed to be using `{{{ formArrows }}}` in my Handlebars template instead of just `{{ formArrows }}`.

This is what I get for not reading the Handlebars documentation before asking.

Comment: Will definitely accept it as soon as I can.   Gotta wait for the cooldown to do so, but I plan to.  :)